# C++ Nested loops cant get the correct output

Tags: c++, loops, nested-loops

I need some help here, anyone know how to code C++ nested loop and output this code, below are my tries but I can't seem to get the correct output.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i;
    i = 0;
    while (i < 9)
    {
        int j;
        j = 0;
        while (j < 9)
        {
            cout << j;
            j = j + 1;
        }
        cout << endl;
        i = i + 1;
    }
}
```

My output is

```
012345678 
012345678 
012345678 
012345678 
012345678 
012345678 
012345678 
012345678 
012345678
```

I expected:

```
000000000
111111111
222222222
333333333
444444444
555555555
666666666
777777777
888888888
```

Comment: 1. please don't link image - copy the output here. 2. in what terms is it wrong? what's expected?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Are you sure you want to output `j` instead of `i`? [https://ideone.com/CSaJcf](https://ideone.com/CSaJcf)

Comment: ahhh alright i get the answer, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Your while loops are what for loops would look like if there were no for loops. Use for loops when you want to iterate a loop counter from some start till some end (and use `while` loops for other, possibly more complicated, conditions):

```
 for (int row=0; row < n_rows; ++row) {
      for (int entry=0; entry < n_entries; ++entry) { 
           do_something(i,j);
      }
      std::cout << "\n";
 }
```

Now you just need to fill in the missing pieces.

The inner loop prints a row of the output. Thats why after the inner loop there is a line break. The output has `n_rows` lines and each line has `n_entries` "entries".

In `do_something` you can do the actual printing:

```
 void do_something(int row,int entry) {
      std::cout << ..... put your code here ....;
 }
```

Now you just need to use the parameters `row` and `entry` to get desired output (hint: you actually need only one of them).